# AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding encrypted video with exoplayer android (JAVA/KOTLIN)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, aes, exoplayer

I am trying to download a video file and encrypt it while downloading then play it using **Exoplaye**r when I search for how to play **AES Video** I found I must make my own **DataSource.** then I try to implement it in many ways but always it gives me that error. (The project is old you might see java and kotlin code together)

**Error**

```
ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
      com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:632)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:602)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
     Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:92)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1017)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

**DataSource**

Reading the Chipher inputStream and decrypt it

```
class EncryptedDataSource(private val key: String) : DataSource {
    private var inputStream: CipherInputStream? = null
    private lateinit var uri: Uri

    override fun addTransferListener(transferListener: TransferListener) {}

    override fun open(dataSpec: DataSpec): Long {
        uri = dataSpec.uri
        try {
            val file = File(uri.path)
            val skeySpec = SecretKeySpec("e9wF6xA6WpTfyjeVrqOnesZD/KGrUDdx".toByteArray(), KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES)
            val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec)
            inputStream = CipherInputStream(file.inputStream(), cipher)
            if (dataSpec.position != 0L) {
                inputStream?.forceSkip(dataSpec.position) // Needed for skipping
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        }
        return dataSpec.length
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun read(buffer: ByteArray, offset: Int, readLength: Int): Int =
        if (readLength == 0) {
            0
        } else {
            inputStream?.read(buffer, offset, readLength) ?: 0
            Log.i("HeshamNyla",inputStream.toString());
        }

    override fun getUri(): Uri? =
        uri

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun close() {
        inputStream?.close()
    }

}
```

**Factory**

```
class EncryptedDataSourceFactory(
    private val key: String
) : DataSource.Factory {
    override fun createDataSource(): EncryptedDataSource =
        EncryptedDataSource(key)
}
```

**Save the bytes**

encrypt and save the downloaded bytes

```
 private void downloadFile(ResponseBody body,Message msg,boolean type)  {

           try {
               int count;
               byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
               long fileSize = body.contentLength()+length;

               InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(body.byteStream(), 1024 * 8);
               File outputFile = new File(new LocalVideos(getApplicationContext()).getFolder()+name);

               OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile,type);
               Cipher encipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PAdding");
               SecretKey skey = new SecretKeySpec("e9wF6xA6WpTfyjeVrqOnesZD/KGrUDdx".getBytes(), KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES);
               //Lgo
               encipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
               CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(bis, encipher);
               CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(output,encipher);

               long total = length;
               long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
               int timeCount = 1;
               while ((count = cis.read(data)) != -1) {

                   total += count;
                   totalFileSize = (int) ((int) (fileSize / (Math.pow(1024, 2))));
                   double current = Math.round(total / (Math.pow(1024, 2)));

                   int progress = (int) ((int) ((total * 100) / fileSize));
                   long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

                   Download download = new Download();
                   download.setTotalFileSize(totalFileSize);

                   if (currentTime > 1000 * timeCount) {

                       download.setCurrentFileSize((int) current);
                       download.setProgress(progress);

                       sendNotification(download);
                       timeCount++;
                   }


                       cos.write(data, 0, count);

               }
               onDownloadComplete(msg);
               cos.flush();
               cos.close();
               bis.close();
           }catch (Throwable exception){
               stopForeground(true);
               stopSelf(msg.arg1);
               notificationManager.cancel(NOTFIYID);
               notificationBuilder.setProgress(0,0,false);
               notificationBuilder.setContentText("Failed try again");
               notificationManager.notify(NOTFIYID, notificationBuilder.build());
               new VideosState(getApplicationContext()).updateVideoState(name,VideosState.STATE_STOPED);
           }


        }
```

**use dataSource**

use dataSource Factory

```
 mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder()
                    .setUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(url)))
                    .build();
            DataSource.Factory dataSource= new EncryptedDataSourceFactory("");

            MediaSource videoSource  = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSource)
                    .createMediaSource(mediaItem);

            playerView.setPlayer(player);
            playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
            player.setPlaybackParameters(parameters);
            player.setMediaSource(videoSource);
            player.prepare();
```